# hotreload on command for openliberty dev mode

Tags: open-liberty, developer-mode

We run openliberty in dev mode for integration testing.
Its a great feature however the problem is that while the developer is still making code changes, openliberty eagerly tries to hotreload every change(I guess its polling for changes every x sec).

This breaks the developer's flow.

Is there a way to tell openliberty to only do hotreload after the developer is finished with their code changes?

**Note:** slow disk access might be contributing to the long openliberty hotreload cycles for us. Unfortunately that is out of our hands so we wanted to know if there is a way to control the hotreload please.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  The short answer is "no".

### Some options:

#### 1. Poll less frequently

The default is every 500ms.  You can use server.xml configuration to increase the polling interval, e.g. `<applicationMonitor pollingRate="3m">`

#### 2. Use debugger Hot Code Replace

Explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77505568/can-maven-open-liberty-plugin-hot-reload-single-class-file-without-stopping-and/77507965#77507965).  As noted, however, there are certain changes, like modifying method signatures, that you can't make via debugger HCR.

### Other thoughts

If you still have thoughts or concerns, let me invite you to reach out to the development team on our Gitter chat channel at: https://gitter.im/OpenLiberty/developer-experience.   Perhaps we could consider a feature enhancement, but it'd be interesting to hear more about your workflow first.

For example, I'm wondering what's so disruptive to your workflow with the current behavior?  If you ultimately have to wait for the last change to take effect in order to exercise the latest behavior, what's the problem if the app is restarting along the way in the meantime?   But that might be better to address in a chat discussion than in this particular question.

Comment: Its the slowness of our machines capability to hotreload. The developer TDD flow is: write test -> change prod code -> wait for a minute or two for hotreload to take effect before they can run their tests.

Comment: I understand the app recycle can take some time and can seem annoying vs. an ideal iterative workflow.  That said, let's consider your suggestion (in the problem title) of having a hot reload "on command".  How would this help?  You'd still need to issue the command before re-running tests again, right?

Comment: you are right. The thinking behind it was that instead of liberty trying to hotreload changes with every key type. We can tell it to reload once we are done and it would speed up the cycle. Maybe :)

Comment: The app would typically update only when the file is saved, which wouldn't be every keystroke unless you had an editor doing some kind of "auto-save" (which maybe you could turn off ?).

Comment: So I'm just wondering if you're saying the final update takes an average amount of time or if you're saying it takes longer because there is a bit of a "backlog" to work through.  E.g. if on a simple, single change an app update takes about 10 seconds, are you seeing the "last" update also taking about 10 seconds?  Or are you seeing it take significantly more than 10 (i.e. the average) number of sec. to restart for this last update (the one after which you're going to run the tests)?